# presentViewController resets all UIView animations

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have two view controllers, A and B. UIView instance viewObject is subview of A in the nib, with frame 0, 0, 100, 100.

Now I execute the following

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{[viewObject setFrame:CGFrameMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];}];
```

It worked all fine. But when I call:

```
[self presentViewController:B animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

viewObject appears to jump back to the frame before the animateWithDuration:animations: message during the transition of the view controllers.

Likewise when I dismiss B the viewObject is at its position in the nib.

How do I make viewObject stay in the same place?

Comment: any chance you're using storyboards autolayouts? it can cause quirks like this

Comment: it is the auto layout...I just had another problem with the auto layout just a while ago but I don't want to disable it :( any workarounds?

Comment: you'll probably need to edit the relevant constraint and make it more 'fluid' -> by default its static and that causes the view to pop right back into the original location when the view layout changes. try to read more [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: have you found a solution for this yet? i'm having the same issue

Comment: I think I stopped using auto layout and it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

try to set

```
[viewObject setClipsToBounds:YES]
```

at least before the second animation. If you need it not to clip to bounds(because of shadows and such) you can reset the property to no after the second animation is completed.

It worked for me every time I had this problem.